# How to treat variable in logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic, modeling, predictor

I have a variable I do not know how I should handle my logistic regression.
The variable is the number of registered students each semester.
If I plot it against my binary outcome, I get the following plot:
[image]

**what kind of explanatory variables should I use? Linear, polynomial, categorical? I feel myself confused when it looks like this and would therefore need some tips.**

Comment: Are you showing us the entire sample? Even a linear relationship would be a stretch with just twelve data points, so higher order terms are pretty much out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Without any other information, a linear term is the obvious choice, since the number of students registered is on a [ratio scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Ratio_scale). This may or may not make sense given all the missing context of the purpose of the study, the nature of the outcome, the other variables available, the sample size, etc.